# Count Gutenberg blocks on the front-end?

Tags: block-editor

Working on my 3rd project using Gutenberg blocks and have a requirement where I need to count the blocks in the loop so I can create, dynamically, a ‘jump to’ menu to various blocks, whatever order they are set as in the post/page.

I can count posts, ACF repeater fields etc in a loop – but is there a similar way to count the blocks, so I can set a conditional ‘If block 2, do x… if block 5 do this… etc’

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`parse_blocks()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/)? Are you sure you want to do this (dynamically?) in frontend and not in the editor?

Comment: I agree with @kero, a custom block in the editor would probably be the best solution.

Comment: My idea was to create a custom block to add a Jump-to menu with anchor links in the front end.  So the jump to options would be created by ACF fields in the page edit screen, with another field for entering a numerical value.  This would be the count of the block.  So you could add a 'contact' jumpto menu and enter no.5 if the contact block was 5th on the page.  As the layouts will vary, they won't be the same in every page, hence why I wanted to add a number in the admin agaisnt the link and in the front end, count the block and link it to the number entered for the jump-to menu.